# Meeting Workspace dates in SharePoint 2013 need "undefined" in URL replaced with "default.aspx"

Tags: meeting-workspace

A similar post was made regarding this question here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/105151/meeting-workspace-dates

Is there a way to add a jQuery code as a Web Part to automatically fix this issue by simply replacing the "undefined" portion of the URL with "default.aspx"? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Meeting workspaces have been discontinued. Check below article:

[Discontinued features and modified functionality in Microsoft SharePoint 2013](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Discontinued-features-and-modified-functionality-in-Microsoft-SharePoint-2013-bbbb0815-2538-4f1d-b647-1f7f6d508c93#__toc382936208)

so I am unable to recreate the issue to provide an exact answer.

But yes, jQuery is a good approach to solving this. Depending on the type of page you are on, a Script Editor webpart can inject the code if you are on a webpart page. If not, adding the code to the master page may be your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("a").each(function () {
            var token = $(this).attr("href");
            token = token.substring(token.indexOf(',"') + 2, token.indexOf('")'));
            $(this).attr("href", "javascript:MtgNavigate2013(\"" + token + "\");");
        });
    });


    function MtgNavigate2013(tokenParam) {
        window.location.href = window.location.href.split("?")[0] + "?InstanceID=" + tokenParam + "&" + g_thispagedata;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: We are facing this undefined error with meeting workspace sites after migrating to SP2013. All the dates on the left hand navigation displays undefined error except the current week's meeting.I added your script to a content editor web part in the home page but that doesn't resolve the error. Am i doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you can still use it by adding some tags to your master page.

```
<%@Register Tagprefix="Meetings" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Meetings" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>
```

just above of `<%@Master language="C#"%>)`

and `<Meetings:CustomToolPaneManager runat="server" />
    <Meetings:PropertyBag runat="server" />`
just below of `<div id="sideNavBox" class="ms-dialogHidden ms-forceWrap ms-noList">`

This solution just works for our SharePoint 2016 OnPrem